# How to proof the inequality related to Schwarz lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

$f: D\to D$ $(D = \{|z| < 1\})$, is a holomorphic function. How to proof 
$$
\left|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}\right| \leq \frac1{1-r^2}, \quad\forall |z_1|,|z_2| \leq r
$$
I try using the Schwarz-Pick theorem which gives,
$$
\left|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{1-\overline{f(z_1)}f(z_2)}\right| \leq \left|\frac{z_1-z_2}{1-\bar z_1 z_2}\right|
$$
then it gives,
$$
\left|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}\right| < \frac2{1-r^2}
$$
Thanks a lot.

Comment: I presume you get to maximizing $|1 - \overline{f(z_1)} f(z_2)|$ and suppose $\overline{f(z_1)} f(z_2) = -1 + \epsilon$?

Comment: $|\frac{f(z_1)-f(z_2)}{z_1-z_2}| \le sup_{z \in z_1z_2}|f'(z)|$ (where $z_1z_2$ is the segment joining the two points which obviously lies within the radius $r$ disc) and then Schwarz-Pick lemma for the derivative trivially gives you the required inequality